# How can I get "binary" of Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am trying to deliver my app to apple review. I made all certificates and so on,the status of program is "Waiting For Upload". Now I must send "binary" using Application Loader. I can't understand,what is binary and didn't find any additional information in their guides.There are some similar questions on stack overflow, but they are outdated, as I think. Can you explain in simple language, what should I do?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html

Comment: @SergeyNikitin Я читал гайды. Там не сказано, где взять compressed binary.

Comment: Отличный ответ - чуть ниже :) При Archive просто выбирается, для чего пакуется - и всё!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Select your device, as where you want to run the app (as opposed to the simulator) but do not run it.
2) Select Product -> Archive
3) Open Window -> Organizer
4) Find your app and select distribute.
5) Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment (yes, this is correct)
6) Save the .ipa file which you can use the Application Loader to send to the App Store.

Comment: It's even simpler if you don't need the application loader. You archive the app, just as kkarayannis said, and then in Step 5 select "distribute to the AppStore".

Comment: That has not always worked for me, and I have seen other people say the same, which is why I suggested Application Loader.

Comment: The user asked for Application Loader, so your answer was perfect. I just wanted to remind people about the fact you may upload directly from Xcode.